# Working with Data.Sequence in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote a program that turned out to be far too slow using lists so I'm trying to switch over to sequences. However, I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax after looking at the documentation.

So far I'm trying to learn with this simple code:

```
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Sequence as S

main :: IO ()
main = do 
       let testSeq = S.empty
       testSeq S.|> 5
       testSeq S.|> 20
       testSeq S.|> 3
       let newSeq = S.update 2 3 testSeq
       let x = lookup 2 testSeq
       print x
```

I've played around with the syntax for a while with no luck but it still has a ton of errors:

```
test.hs:9:8:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a0’
                with actual type ‘S.Seq Integer’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: testSeq S.|> 5
    In the expression:
      do { let testSeq = S.empty;
           testSeq S.|> 5;
           testSeq S.|> 20;
           testSeq S.|> 3;
           .... }
    In an equation for ‘main’:
        main
          = do { let testSeq = ...;
                 testSeq S.|> 5;
                 testSeq S.|> 20;
                 .... }

test.hs:10:8:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a1’
                with actual type ‘S.Seq Integer’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: testSeq S.|> 20
    In the expression:
      do { let testSeq = S.empty;
           testSeq S.|> 5;
           testSeq S.|> 20;
           testSeq S.|> 3;
           .... }
    In an equation for ‘main’:
        main
          = do { let testSeq = ...;
                 testSeq S.|> 5;
                 testSeq S.|> 20;
                 .... }

test.hs:11:8:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a2’
                with actual type ‘S.Seq Integer’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: testSeq S.|> 3
    In the expression:
      do { let testSeq = S.empty;
           testSeq S.|> 5;
           testSeq S.|> 20;
           testSeq S.|> 3;
           .... }
    In an equation for ‘main’:
        main
          = do { let testSeq = ...;
                 testSeq S.|> 5;
                 testSeq S.|> 20;
                 .... }

test.hs:13:25:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[(Integer, b)]’
                with actual type ‘S.Seq a3’
    Relevant bindings include x :: Maybe b (bound at test.hs:13:12)
    In the second argument of ‘lookup’, namely ‘testSeq’
    In the expression: lookup 2 testSeq
```

I'm new to Haskell so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How would you do the same thing with lists?

Comment: Trying to force a Haskell program into the "sequence of statements" model of other languages doesn't usually lead to A Good Place.

Comment: Your last edit completely changed the question, please don't do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like almost everything in Haskell, `Seq` is a purely functional data structure. It's not like an imperative stack where you push stuff to, mutating the original structure. Rather, like ordinary lists, you just generate new container-values which have the extra elements, but this does not affect the old shorter seqs in any way. So, the program you've asked about should just be

```
testSeq :: S.Seq Int
testSeq = S.update 2 3 $ S.empty S.|> 5 S.|> 20 S.|> 30

main :: IO ()
main = print $ S.lookup 2 testSeq
```

(It has to be [`S.lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:lookup), or equivalently `S.!?`. By itself, [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup) is a function that works on plain lists!)

Note that this doesn't really give you any advantage over

```
testSeq = S.update 2 3 $ S.fromList [5,20,30]
```

In fact, lists are usually *faster* than `Seq`, they just don't allow efficient random access.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. I'm getting a not in scope error though, on the S.lookup. I was getting the same in the question code I edited (sorry about that).

Comment: Hm, what version of the package are you using? (`cabal info containers`) `lookup` has only been added quite recently to the `Sequence` module (0.5.8), before it had only [`index`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.0/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:index), which you can also use (but it doesn't have a safe length-check).

Comment: This still feels like an x/y issue.  If @Strobe00 desires fast random access/update of elements in an ordered set then they'll probably be better served by a map structure.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I ended up going with IO Arrays and it's so much faster now.

Comment: Sounds fitting. That or an STArray.

Comment: @Strobe00 though there are use cases where mutable arrays give you better performance than any alternative, I would recommend you only use them as a last-resort optimisation. Many algorithms can be implemented just as efficiently using only purely-functional tools (_most_ I daresay, if you include immutable packed vectors) and only that way do you actually profit from Haskell's great safety guarantees. Using Haskell with mutable arrays is more like writing C with needlessly clunky syntax. Especially, while learning Haskell it makes sense to stick completely to lists to get a feel for it.